# The springAOP of pointcut using @annotation is not effective when applied to IbatisDAO

Tags: spring-aop, ibatis, spring-aspects

**Annotation:**

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface IbatisAnno {}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class IbatisAsepct {
    
    //not works
    @Pointcut("@annotation(xxx.IbatisAnno)")
    public void m(){}

    //works
    @Pointcut("execution(* xxx.xxDAO.*(..))")
    public void m2(){}

    @Before("m()")
    public void testM(){
        System.out.println("Before   Method...............");
    }


    @Before("m2()")
    public void testM2(){
        System.out.println("Before   Method2...............");
    }
}
```

**Target class:**

```java
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
public class IbatisOfferFeedDAO extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements OfferFeedDAO{
   @IbatisAnno
   public void xxx(){
      this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().insert();
   }
}
```

Aspect does not take effect when using `@Pointcut("@annotation(xxx.IbatisAnno)")`, but it works when using `@Pointcut("execution(* xxx.xxDAO.*(..))")`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I see no obvious reason why it would not work, unless you have a typo in the annotation's fully qualified class name. By the way, you ought to move `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()` from a random application class to a dedicated `@Configuration` class, even though it does not seem to cause your problem here if you say it works with the other pointcut on the same target class. It just looks super ugly and is hard to maintain.

Comment: thanks,but the aspect is effective when I apply this annotation to a ordinary target class

Comment: In order to help you I first need to be able to reproduce your problem. Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), publish it on GitHub and then notify me again so I can take a look. If you cannot explain more clearly, let your code speak, that is the best way to get a solution for your problem.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: A classical Spring AOP beginner's mistake is to use target classes which are not Spring beans. Spring AOP only works with Spring components. If you cannot make your class a `@Component` or otherwise declare it as a `@Bean`, you still have the option of using AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. You find dozens of answers here explaining that and the Spring manual also explains it.

Comment: thanks,the problem has been solved, because the target class has been proxied by ibatis during the startup process, resulting in the loss of annotations, so the aspect not work through the way of @Pointcut("@annotation(xxx.IbatisAnno)")

Comment: Then please write a comprehensive answer with code and explanation for the benefit of everyone, ideally in a way enabling us to reproduce your situation. That way you can return something to the community you asked for help. Later you can also accept your own answer and thus close the question which is now still listed as unanswered. Thank you.